# How to make page full height on IOS9

Tags: css, responsiveness

Rightblock is not fullheight on mobile devices. In bootsrap i removed responsive features, such as `col-md-*` replaced to `col-xs-*`
On IOS8 devices everything is ok (via browserstack). Left block has `height:78vh`. How to make it simple fixed layout and disable scaling in safari browser

```html
<div class="wrapcontent">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <header id="header"></header>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="content" class="content clearfix">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="flex-container ng-scope">
        <div class="col-xs-8 leftBlock">...</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 rightBlock">...</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <footer id="footer" class="footer clearfix"></footer>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

```css
.wrapContent {
  overflow: visible!important;
  height: auto!important;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -71px;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  background: #323742;
}
.header {
  overflow: visible;
  height: 189px;
}
.col-xs-12 {
  float: left;
}
.flex-container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: -15px;
}
.leftBlock {
  min-height: 78vh;
  float: left;
}
.rightBlock {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #e5e9ec;
  background: #f6f6fa;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should provide any cod examples of your website to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to remove

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```